# How work with Facebook Page Subscription Messaging

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, chatbot, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I'm working on Facebook Messenger chatbot and I've found documentation about Facebook Page Subscription Messaging. This feature allow your bot to send messages to users, outside of the "stardard" 24 hours messaging.

[Facebook's documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/policy/page-subscription-messaging/) explains what is Subscription Messaging 
but I've not found more details about how implement it.

My questions:

- Is there any back-office to be able to send this kind of message ? For example to allow a Community Manager to send this messages
- In the case where to do code is mandatory, I suppose I have to build a Facebook's users list and use it to send "Subscription Message" type to each. Can I send these messages to these users at the same time or I have to do some packets or add a small timeout between each messages ?
- What happends if I send a "Subscribe Message" to an user who have unsubscribed to my bot's messages ?

Thanks !

Comment: 1. No, 2. You have to formulate the necessary request per individual recipient; but you can send multiple of those to the API in a _batch_ to save on costly HTTP requests, 3. You’d get an error message back from the API.

Comment: Thanks @misorude :)